# Are there any great LEGO designers that are well-known?

Tags: sets, design

I know that many designers work for LEGO but I was wondering if there was some 'Star Designers' that we should know by name.  Of course, I would also like to know what they are famous for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there are more and more LEGO fans who become designers, some of them are already well known from the community and are very dedicated to fans, [going to events](http://creator.lego.com/en-gb/Designers/Blog/ReadMore/Default.aspx?id=4655065) and the like. They are actually just regular people and always have an amused look if you treat them like they have ascended to godhood status or something.

A few of them in no particular order:

- [Pierre Normandin](http://railbricks.com/blog/lego-designer-pierre-normandin-talks-about-the-maersk-train/)

  Pierre works on CITY and is known among others for [10129 Maersk Train](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10219-1) and [3677 Red Cargo Train](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=3677-1).
- [Mark Stafford](http://www.brothers-brick.com/2009/01/11/from-lego-fan-to-lego-set-designer-the-mark-stafford-interview-part-1/)

  Mark works on most fantasy themes and keeps [a list of his sets](http://www.mocpages.com/folder.php/45067), also on [brickset](http://www.brickset.com/brickLists/?5289)
- [Melody Caddick](http://www.couriermail.com.au/ipad/fan-who-built-a-career-out-of-lego/story-fn6ck8la-1226268490775)

  We owe Mel some exlusive sets, including [3300003 LEGO Brand Retail Store](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=3300003-1), [3300001 Brickley](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=3300001-1) and some (if not all, I'm not sure) [Master Builder Academy](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Master%20Builder%20Academy) sets. Mel also finalised the design of the first ever LEGO cuusoo set: [21101 Hayabusa](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=21101-1)
- Megan Rothrock

  Megan worked for the ill-fated LEGO Universe MMORPG, but doesn't work for LEGO any longer. She focuses on [LEGO fan events](http://www.thelegoshow.com/) and is now publishing [her own book](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-lego-adventure-book-vol-1-megan-h-rothrock/1113340034).
- [Jamie Berard](http://creator.lego.com/en-gb/Designers/Bios/Default.aspx), as cited in another answer
- [Markus Kossman](http://technic.lego.com/en-us/Designers/Bios/Markus%20Kossman.aspx)

  Markus is responsible for some huge Technic sets, including [8421 Mobile Crane] and the first Power Functions sets, [8275 Motorized Bulldozer](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=8275-1)

As you can see, LEGO now has online profiles for [Technic](http://technic.lego.com/en-us/Designers/Bios/Default.aspx) and [Creator](http://creator.lego.com/en-gb/Designers/Bios/Default.aspx) designers (maybe others, but I didn't see any), and of course the [LEGO Designer Videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7878A84E49036111) Youtube channel.

Also, LEGO has also issued [sets designed by fans](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/290/does-lego-market-sets-that-were-designed-by-fans), which is the closest you can be of being a designer without being actually one. Note that some of the names on that list did eventually become full-fledged designers themselves.

To end, a little piece of trivia: the license plates on [some vehicles](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4202-1) usually bear the initials of the designer of the set. Have fun hunting them...

Answer (score 7):

The most obvious one I guess is Erling Dideriksen, who was not only a [Chief Designer on the LEGO City range](https://talent.me/erling-dideriksen), but also designed the element that many refer to as "The Erling Brick".

[image: Headlight or Erling Brick]

The LEGO Group have also started recently publishing videos of their designers talking about new sets they've worked on (especially the Lord of the Rings sets), which will bring more of their designers into the public eye.

Comment: These videos are definitely worth viewing.

Comment: @Joubarc - I think you meant to comment on Kramii's post ;)

Comment: Well, you talked about them too, didn't you?

Comment: Oh, yes, I suppose I did - I just didn't post any links, and forgot I'd mentioned them ;)

Answer (score 6):

[Jamie](http://creator.lego.com/en-gb/Designers/Bios/Default.aspx) [Berard](http://news.lugnet.com/mediawatch/?n=2733) designed some beautiful sets, including:

- [10194 Emerald Night](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10194-1)
- [10182 Café Corner](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10182-1)
- [10185 Green Grocer](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10185-1)
- [10197 Fire Brigade](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10197-1)
- [10233 Horizon Express](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10233-1)

Not only that, but he's done a lot of promotional work, including some interesting [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?q=jamie%20berard&hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bpcl=38897761&biw=1525&bih=639&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=w1) videos and an excellent presentation called "[Stressing the Elements](http://bramlambrecht.com/tmp/jamieberard-brickstress-bf06.pdf)".

Comment: 10219 is from pierre Normandin

Comment: @Joubarc: You're quite right of course. Thanks for picking this up.