# How can I contact LEGO set designers?

Tags: design

I would like to contact some of the set designers of the LEGO group to take part in a professional design forum, but I can't find any contact information. Is there a way I can contact them, or find more information on how to contact them?

Answer (score 6):

Considering individual designers would need to ask for permissions from LEGO to do this, it may be more efficient not to contact them directly, but to go through the [community team](http://ceeteamblog.com/2014/01/03/lego-novelties-confidentiality/).

If that doesn't work, it's true that some designers do have an active online presence (check the answer to [Are there any great LEGO designers that are well-known?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1681/99)) and shouldn't be too hard to get in touch with. There's always a chance they'll have to send you back to the community team or a legal team somewhere, but I suppose it's worth a try.

Anyway, we need them to spend their time on designing sets, so let's hope you don't demand too much of their time.

Comment: There are also former LEGO designers, like Mariann Asanuma. you can find her on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Model-Building-Secrets/112066427547 and if you want to skip straight to her site: http://modelbuildingsecrets.com/

Comment: Great!Big thank you!I actually managed to find some contacts in LinkedIn. Won't steal your designers for too long, promise!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Cuusoo](http://blog.lego.cuusoo.com/)? That seems to be a less formal designer's interface to the public.

Comment: Haven't, but will. Thank you!